# Machine cycles in x86 CPU after assembly instruction

Tags: assembly, cpu, cpu-architecture, cpu-registers

Theoretically I have Intel 8086 and I want to run this instruction:

```
add [2000], 6 (or in AT&T syntax: addw $6, 2000)
```

I also know that:

- at 2000 value is 2
- at 3000 is register CS
- at 6000 is register DS
- at 1000 is register IP

Now I want to describe machine cycle in this CPU: fetch & execute.

I know how it looks in theory:

Fetch:

- fetch an instruction from memory
- decode the instruction to determine the operations
- fetch data from memory if necessary

Execute:

- perform the operation on the data
- store the result in memory if needed

But I don't know how it looks with real CPU registers and assembly code. Can you explain this?

Comment: You might want to specify if you mean a byte add or a word add. I have arbitrarily decided that you want a word add.

Comment: The real world is far too complex to answer on StackOverflow. You can get a start on [Agner Fog's Web site](http://agner.org/optimize/). "The microarchitecture of Intel, AMD and VIA CPUs" is a good start.

Comment: @RaymondChen OP specifically says he has an 8086.

Comment: @fuz deleted my prior comment about the addw implying word size. I will delete this comment later.

Comment: A real 8086 takes 23 cycles to execute that instruction, assuming its already in the prefetch queue and there's no memory wait states. I don't think it's documented anywhere what exactly the 8086 is doing during those 23 cycles, but there would be 4 cycles each for the read and write to memory, at least 6 cycles for calculating the effective address.

Comment: @fuz But the title says x86, which covers many more processors than just the 8086.

Answer (score 2):

The values in memory or registers don't matter. When

```
        add     word ptr ds:[02000h],00006h
```

is executed, the cpu reads 16 bit value 2 from location 2000 into an internal (unnamed) register, adds 6 to the 2, and stores and stores 16 bit value 8 into location 2000 (little endian format). At least two web sites shows this as taking 23 cycles (17 for instruction + 6 for the effective addressing).

Comment: And if `cs:ip` was `3000:1000` before fetch, then after fetch&decode (ahead of execution) the `cs:ip` will be `3000:1005`. (if I guessed the 16b opcode correctly).